# Linux: find command performance issue

Tags: linux, performance, find

I need the list of files in some directory and so I am using this command to find files on linux machine:

```
find /some_directory -depth -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec basename {} \;
```

But it is taking a lot of time (~ 35 mins) as there are more than 200k files. Can this be optimized or is there a better alternative?

Comment: Can't you use `ls`?

Comment: I'm wondering why didn't you post that on Unix/Linux community !

Comment: The `-depth` option makes no sense in combination with `-mindepth 1` and `-maxdepth 1`. Remove it.

Comment: Anyhow. 200000 files aren't much. Look at your file system performance. I agree that this question is off topic on stackoverflow.

Comment: Asked the same question on Unix/Linux community - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388492/improve-performance-of-find-exec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-printf` to emulate `basename` and this will eliminate the need for any additional processes:

```
find /some_directory -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -printf '%f\n'
```

Comment: No, it won't; basename also strips extensions ;}

Comment: @tink `basename` will **optionally** strip extensions but the OP did not specify that option.

Answer (score 2):

The low performance is due to the overhead of calling `basename` 200,000 times. Run `find` without the `-exec` option and pipe the output to a script in Python or some other good language that will convert path names to basenames, e.g.:

basename.py:

```
import os,sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print(os.path.basename(line), end='')
```

Shell:

```
find /some_directory -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 | python basename.py
```